# Change site name programmatically

Tags: 8, configuration

We have a requirement that when we save a node that nodes title should be the site name. We used to do it in Drupal 7. But I was not able to find the proper method for it in Drupal 8.

This is what we tried:

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('system.site');
$config->set('system.site.name', "Demo Site");
$config->save();
```

Got it from here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/simple-configuration-api

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where, in what hook, are you executing that code? It needs to be just `name` in  `$config->set('name', "Demo Site");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly :

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('system.site');
$config->set('name', "XXXXXXX"); 
$config->save();
```

Just have to implement hook_node_update to fit your needs.

Comment: Please don't comment your own answer. Please just update it with a little bit of explanation.

Comment: hook_node_presave would be better as hook_node_update does not run when a new node is added.